# How to fire a method on camera capture click in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on a iPhone application which has a main functionality video capture.
How can I fire a method when a user started video recording ??

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [UIImagePickerController Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Comment: Yeah read this page http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH3-SW47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when You click on camera recoding .

After that you can check by

```
If ([imagePickerController startVideoCapture] == yes)
{
   // Fire your method here.
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "when You click on camera recoding"

Comment: As your question i could understand that you need to fire a method after camera recording has been started once.Am i right ? Then after camera recording started than you can check by this method as camera is in recording mode or not.If it is YES then you can fire your method  in IF condition .

Comment: Here is my code in this i am fire a method after recording has been started.- (IBAction)createVideo {       

    
   NSTimer * gameTimer = [[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.00 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:gameTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    
     if([imagePicker startVideoCapture]==YES)
            {
                fire your method
            }

        }
       

        return;
    }

Comment: Can you please explain more , what you exactly want to perform ?

Comment: Yea I will explain...thanks for your helping mentality

I want to start a timer when I click record button
ans also is there  any way to add a label on cameraview,with out hiding cam controls ?

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerController Class reference has instant method for image capturing, start and stop video recording.

Below is the copy of apple Doc for UIImagePickerController Class.

startVideoCapture
Starts video capture using the camera specified by the UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice property.

- (BOOL)startVideoCapture
  Return Value
  YES on success or NO on failure. This method may return a value of NO for various reasons, among them the following:

Movie capture is already in progress
The device does not support movie capture
The device is out of disk space
Discussion
Use this method in conjunction with a custom overlay view to initiate the programmatic capture of a movie. You can take more than one movie without leaving the interface, but to do so requires you to hide the default image picker controls.

Calling this method while a movie is being captured has no effect. You must call the stopVideoCapture method, and then wait until the associated delegate object receives an imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: message, before you can capture another movie.

Calling this method when the source type of the image picker is set to a value other than UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera results in the throwing of an NSInvalidArgumentException exception.

If you require additional options or more control over movie capture, use the movie capture methods in the AV Foundation framework. Refer to AV Foundation Framework Reference.

Availability
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
Declared In
UIImagePickerController.h
stopVideoCapture
Stops video capture.

- (void)stopVideoCapture
  Discussion
  After you call this method to stop video capture, the system calls the image picker delegate’s imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method.

Availability
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
Declared In
UIImagePickerController.h

You can also get this from [Apple Doc class ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)